# Asp.net core Chrome Issue with Cookies

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, razor

I have a strange issue, we are running a asp.net core razor app.
There are no issues logging into Firefox or Edge.

But rather randomly, we have an issue in Chrome that we can't figure out.

(Random as in, it has occurred on user's machines randomly before and now **it is occurring on a lot of machines, but still not all of them**)

The issue is that it seems that our "auth-token" cookie is not being set.

To me, it seems that the error is with this line which runs after a successful username and password, but before a redirect.

```
...
Response.Cookies.Append("auth-token", inToken, option);
...
```

There is no error, but a line that runs almost immediately after falls over

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var name = "auth-token";
    var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[name]; //THIS LINE DOESN'T HAVE THE COOKIE CALLED "auth-token" IN CHROME
    ...
}
```

We have tried:

Incognito Chrome/Clearing Cache/Cookies in Chrome

- Restarting Machine
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling chrome
- Installing old versions of Chrome (chromium)
- Running an old version of our code (which previously worked on chrome)

There doesn't seem to be a clear cause for when this issue occurs.

I would love to figure out why this is happening or if possible any information on how I could capture what is happening.

Thank you!

Comment: I've just realized, I ran into the similar issue: cookie is not accepted by Chrome in my razor pages net.core 3.1 anymore. It was all good but now cookie dialog closes and opens again after page reload. No issues with Edge. Have not yet dig deeper.

Comment: Yeah I can find alot of information on chrome, cookies and their implementation withing .net core 3.1. But nothing that clearly addresses this issue.

Comment: Have you tried with 2.1? 2.1 is working fine for me, probably I have some migration issue, will see.

Comment: Our older version of the code was running 2.2 and it was working.
But after spending a while trawling the internet I figure out my issue.
I will post it in a sec, but my solution still doesn't explain why it wouldn't work with 3.1... I am puzzled!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After many hours researching it seems I have finally fixed my issue.

By setting the following in our cookie

```
SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
```

or

```
SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict
```

**Our Chrome issues have been fixed**

I was reading about Google Chrome's "SameSite" cookie options.

https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site

Originally I thought this was unrelated as SameSite has been forced in Chrome for quite a wile now, and it has never bothered our code. But I still tried setting:

```
SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
```

To no changes

After bringing this up to my boss he informed me that he noticed an old warning that appeared in the chrome console for <1 second.

> 'A cookie associated with a resource at ... was set with
> 'SameSite=None' but without 'Secure'. It has been blocked....'

(Note: This was before I tried messing around with SameSite Options at all and was part of some code to fix a Safari bug)

So naturally we managed to capture the error with a quick screenshot and then we added in the SameSite option with Strict.

So I while it works for me now it still doesn't explain;

- Why didn't it break earlier, we have been using versions of chrome with it for several months
- Why does it still not break if I run an old version of the code with .net 2.1 (without any SameSite Options adjusted)
- Why does our new version of the code **without** the adjusted SameSite option still work on some user's machines

Comment: Chrome has had the warning for a while, but has just recently implemented it. It expects a SameSite cookie now or it will block it and SameSite None must be secure. It could be that some of your users haven't updated to the newest chrome, or they have existing cookies that can still be used.
Note that SameSite.None isn't actually setting it to "None" at the moment (Pretty big bug with this change!), when None is required, modifying the Path to "/; SameSite=None" works.

Comment: Ah right!
That seems to answer most of my queries around this.
I don't know why I was unable to find any of that online, but oh well.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Works for me but I am curious why my settings in web.config didn't apply here. My cookies where displaying as samesite lax but if I didn't explicitly set this in code behind it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just tried in my project and it works! This saved me a lot of time! p.s. my previous version w. 2.1 is still working fine...

Comment: Yeah... I am very happy it is working now myself, but the fact that it seems to work/not work in certain situations still boggles the mind.If anyone can find why it works the way it does it would be nice to know!